# why the order of quantifiers are important? how the order is determined?

Tags: logic

I want to know why the order of quantifiers are important in a logic formula?
When I read books about logic programming, such points are mentioned, but did not say why.
Is there any one could explain with some examples?
Also, how can we determine order of quantifiers from a given logic formula?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

You would be well advised to read a book about [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) before the books about
logic programming.

Consider the true statement:

**1**.  *Everybody has a mother*

Let's formalize it in FOL. To keep it simple, we'll say
that the universe of discourse is the set of *people*, i.e.
our individual variables `x`, `y`, `z`... range over *people*. Then
**1** becomes:

**1F**. `(x)(Ey)Mother(y,x)`

which we can read as: *For every person `x` there exists
some person `y` such that `y` is the mother of `x`*.

Now let's swap the order of the universal quantifier `(x)` and existential
quantifier `(Ey)`:

**2F**. `(Ey)(x)Mother(y,x)`

That reads: *There is some person `y` such that for every person `x`,
`y` is the mother of `x`*. Or in plain English:

**2**.  *There is somebody who is the mother of everybody*

You see that swapping the quantifiers changes the meaning of the statement,
taking us from the true statement **1** to the false statement **2**. Indeed, to the *absurdly* false statement
**2**, which entails that somebody is their own mother.

That's why the order of quantifiers matters.

> how can we determine order of quantifiers from a given logic formula?

Well, in **1F** and **2F**, for example, all the variables are already bound by quantifiers,
so there's nothing to determine. The order of the quantifiers is what you see,
left to right.

Suppose one of the variables was free (not bound), e.g.

**3F**. `(Ey)Mother(y,x)`

You might read that as: *There is someone who is the mother of `x`, for variable person `x`*.

But this formula really doesn't express any *statement*. It expresses a *unary predicate* of persons, the predicate *Someone is the mother of `x`*. If you free up the remaining variable:

**4F**. `Mother(x,y)`

then you have the *binary* predicate, or relation: *`x` is the mother of `y`*.

A formula with 1,2,...,*n* free variables expresses a unary, binary,...,*n*-ary predicate.

Given a predicate, you can make a statement by binding free variables with quantifiers and/or substituting individual constants for the free variables. From **4F** you can make:

```
(x)(y)Mother(x,y)       (Everybody is everybody's mother)
(Ex)(y)Mother(x,y)      (Somebody is everybody's mother)
(Ex)(Ey)Mother(x,y)     (Somebody is somebody's mother)
(x)Mother(x,Arnold)     (Everybody is the mother of Arnold)
(x)Mother(Bernice,x)    (Bernice is the mother of everybody)
Mother(Arnold,Bernice)  (Arnold is the mother of Bernice)
...
...
```

and so on *ad nauseam*.

What this should make clear is that if a formula has free variables, and therefore expresses
a predicate, the formula as such *does not imply* any particular way of quantifying
the free variables, or that they should be quantified at all.

Comment: thanks, you made clear many things for me. sometimes it is easier to listen rather than reading in books. :)

Comment: even after years, it is too helpful.